# wxMDIChildFrame inside wxPanel

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I would like some of my application to have an MDI interface using multiple wxMDIChildFrame's, but I would like these child frames to be inside a wxPanel as opposed to inside a wxMDIParentFrame (I need a so called wxMDIParentPanel).

The reason I would like this is because my application is (for the most part) and Aui application with wxAuiNotebook tabs - however I would like ONE of these tabs to contain multiple MDI windows inside of it.

My issue arises due to the fact that the wxMDIChildFrame requires a wxMDIParentFrame as its parent, and I am not sure how to overcome this.

I have asked a similar question here: https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=47756

Comment: I don't think its generally possible to have a mix of AUI with non-AUI classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use real MDI (i.e. as supported natively by MSW) inside anything other than `wxMDIParentFrame`. You can use AUI-based MDI-like interface inside any window, but then you should just use AUI classes directly.